# Very large plots - generated on the fly?

Tags: javascript, python, r, struct

I have two very simple functions in python that calculate the size of a struct (C struct, numpy struct, etc) given the range of numbers you want to store. So, if you wanted to store numbers from 0 to 8389798, 8389798 would be the value you feed the function:

```
def ss(value):
    nbits = 8
    while value > 2**nbits:
        nbits += 8
    return nbits * value

def mss(value):
    total_size = 0
    max_bits = [(0,0)] # (bits for 1 row in struct, max rows in struct)
    while value > 2 ** max_bits[-1][0] :
        total_size += max_bits[-1][0] * max_bits[-1][1]
        value -= max_bits[-1][1]
        new_struct_bits = max_bits[-1][0]+8
        max_bits.append( (new_struct_bits,2**new_struct_bits) )
    total_size += max_bits[-1][0] * value
    #print max_bits
    return total_size
```

ss is for a single struct where you need as many bytes in the first row to store "1" as you would in the last row to store "8389798". However, this is not as space efficient as breaking your struct up into structs of 1 byte, 2 bytes, 3 bytes, etc, up until N bytes needed to store your value. This is what mss calculates.

So now i want to see how much more efficient mss is over ss for a range of values - that range being 1 to, say, 100 billion. That's much to much data to save and plot, and it's totally unnecessary to do so in the first place. Far better to take the plot window, and for every value of X that has a pixel in that window, calculate the value of y [which is ss(x) - mss(x)].

This sort of interactive graph is really the only way i can think of to look at the relationship between mss and ss. Does anyone know how i should plot such a graph? I'm willing to use a JavaScript solution because I can rewrite the python to that, as well as use "solutions" like Excel, R, Wolfram, if they offer a way to do interactive/generated graphs.

Comment: adaptive sampling might be what you are after.

Comment: why cant you just compute ss(x)-mss(x) for a number of equally spaced values between 1 and 100,000,000,000 and plot that, first as points and then maybe join the dots? Or is it non-linear enough to not look good when plotted like that? Do it on a log scale? Why do you need an interactive graph? Isn't a static plot okay?